# Targeting all children of parent

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all the label elements (with children) using JQuery, but I think I'm getting confused...

I tried the following, along with a variation of other attempts, but I can't seem to be retrieving more than 1 label... What did I miss?

Thanks! S.

```
   $(".tasks section p a[class=add-task]").click(function(){
      var obj = $(this).parent().parent().children(".tasks .task > label").html();
      alert(obj);
   });
```

with the following content:

```
<section class="tasks">
   <h2>Listes de taches</h2>
   <section class="task" id="list-1">
      <h3>Liste 1</h3>

      <label for="list-1_task-1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="list-1_task-1" value="value">
         Tache 1 <span class="notification">1</span>
      </label>              


      <label for="list-1_task-2">
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="list-1_task-2" value="value">
         Tache 2 <span class="notification">2</span>
      </label>              

      <p><a href="#" class="add-task" id="add-task:1">Ajouter une tache</a></p>
```

Comment: why make it so difficult? just use the `$('.task > label')` selector

Comment: `$(this).closest('.tasks').find('label')`

Comment: Because `.html()` returns html of only first matched element in set

Comment: @VDesign `$('.task > label')` will select ALL on the page, it looks like OP is trying to select those in each particular section only.

Comment: @Popnoodles: ok correct in that case the answer of adeneo would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many easy ways to do this:

One, sibling selector:

```
$("a.add-task").click(function(){
    var labels = $(this).parent().siblings("label");
});
```

Two, parent selector:

```
$("a.add-task").click(function(){
    var labels = $(this).parents('.task').children("label");
});
```

Selecting by tag name (using find):

```
$("a.add-task").click(function(){
    var labels = $(this).parents('.task').find("label");
});
```

You will get all the label elements in your `.task` div which you clicked the a.add-task link.

After you get the labels, you have to use `$.each` or `labels.each` method to loop and get every item's html.

```
labels.each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();

    // do whatever you want.
});
```

Comment: `$(this).parents('task')` will select nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.each()` since `.html()` would get `innerHtml` of the first instance only,

```
$(".tasks section p a.add-task").click(function () {
    var obj = "";

    $(this).parent().siblings("label").each(function(){
      obj += $(this).html();
    })

    alert(obj);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXx7N/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code `$(this).parent().parent().children(".tasks .task > label")` return more then one HTML object. And the .html() returns html of only first matched element (according to **@A. Wolff** comment). So you should use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$(".tasks section p a[class=add-task]").click(function(){
    var obj = "";
    $(this).parent().parent().children(".tasks .task > label").each(function(){
       obj += $(this).html();
    });
     alert(obj);
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Na9Gj/)